# Using async/await in node 8.5

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm using the latest version of nodejs on windows and am getting this error:

```
if(await fnA()) {
         ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Here's my code:

```
if(await fnA()) {
    console.log("1");    
} else {
    console.log("error at 1: ");
}

async function fnA() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if(await fnB()) {
            console.log("A"); 
            resolve(true);   
        } else {
            console.log("error at A: ");
            reject();
        }
    });
}

function fnB() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("fnB");
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("fnB after delay");
            resolve(true);
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

I tried moving the `await` outside of the if condition, and am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not have `await` outside of an `async` function, yet.

The error you got was because of that. So wrap your `if` inside an `async` function or something.

Comment: That just moved the error onto the next `await` designation:
`if (await fnB()) {`
                  ^^^
` `
`SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: I added async to the anonymous callback functions and that fixed that.  Cheers!